# Adjusting center of nine-patch png

Tags: android, nine-patch

I have a nine-patch png that I'm using as a popup bubble.  It looks like this:

[image: yellow popup bubble with pointer]

I'm putting it in an TextView of width fill_parent so the bubble expands the width of the screen.  As one might expect, the pointer at the top is then centered horizontally in the middle of the screen.

What is the easiest way to adjust the location of the pointer so that it's, say, 5/8ths of the way over from the left instead of centered?

I can re-cut the png if necessary.

**UPDATE:** Cubic has a very simple solution to the problem that I can't believe I missed.  It works very effectively for my current problem. However, one downside with this solution is that it can't be adjusted on the fly.  If I need to put the pointer in one place for one view, but a different place for another view, I need to cut two different PNGs.  Is there a solution that can be adjusted at runtime?

Comment: Consider not making the pixels under the pointer stretchable to maintain the size and angle of the pointer - if that is desirable.

Answer (score 4):

You have a balanced stretch at the moment with one dot on each side. Can you try adding more to the left or right?

Comment: Ah yes, I would like to know the answer to that too. I guess you could do it with a slightly complex view structure but it may be more efficient just to have different pngs.